# Is the XOR two block ciphers still a block cipher?

Tags: block-cipher, decryption, tweakable-cipher

Let's say I have a block cipher $E: K \times M \rightarrow C$.

Is the function defined by $\operatorname{Enc}(k_1,k_2,m) =  E(k_1, m)\ \operatorname{XOR}\ E(k_2,m)$ guaranteed to have an inverse function $\operatorname{Dec}$?

If it has, then what is $\operatorname{Dec}(k_1,k_2,c)$?

Comment: I take it this is homework? If so, think about what one requires to be able to invert an XOR operation. Are all these prerequisites present in the decryption case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the function defined by $\operatorname{Enc}(k_1,k_2,m) =  E(k_1, m)\ \operatorname{XOR}\ E(k_2,m)$ guaranteed to have an [inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) $\operatorname{Dec}$?

We have a definition problem for "inverse function". In the form stated, $\operatorname{Enc}: K \times K \times M \rightarrow C$, and since for a block cipher $|M|=|C|$, the source set for $\operatorname{Enc}$ is larger by a factor $|K|^2$ than the destination set, thus $\operatorname{Enc}$ could be invertible only if $K$ had 1 or no element.

Thus we want to change the question to: does it hold that for all (or is it for some) fixed $(k_1,k_2)$, the function $\operatorname{Enc}_{(k_1,k_2)}: M \rightarrow C$ defined by $\operatorname{Enc}_{(k_1,k_2)}(m)=\operatorname{Enc}(k_1,k_2,m)$ is guaranteed to have an inverse function?

*NO* in general.

- In the "for all" reading, a simple counterexample is $k_1=k_2$: in this case $\operatorname{Enc}_{(k_1,k_2)}(m)$ is always the same element (the all-zero bit vector), thus (unless $M$ has 1 or 0 elements) $\operatorname{Enc}_{(k_1,k_2)}$ is not [injective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function), thus has no inverse function.
- Even if we excluded $k_1=k_2$, the answer is still no when $E$ is an arbitrary block cipher. Proof sketch: for a block cipher $E$ construct another $E'$ with a key one bit wider, that ignores the rightmost key bit. Then for any key $k$ for $E$, the couple of keys $(k'_1,k'_2)=(k\mathbin\|0,k\mathbin\|1)$ for $E'$ is a counterexample for $E'$.
- If we change "for all" to "for some", then the answer depends on $E$.

  - It's possible to exhibit an $E$ such that there's no $(k_1,k_2)$ making $\operatorname{Enc}_{(k_1,k_2)}$ invertible.
  - It's also possible to exhibit an $E$ and a $(k_1,k_2)$ such that $\operatorname{Enc}_{(k_1,k_2)}$ is invertible, at least if we make no security claim on $E$.

  *Remark*: If we model $E_{k_1}$ and $E_{k_2}$ as pseudo-random permutations, then for fixed $(k_1,k_2)$ the probability that $\operatorname{Enc}_{(k_1,k_2)}$ is invertible decreases exponentially with $|M|$. Thus if $\log_2|K|$ and $\log_2|M|$ grow in proportion (e.g. the key is at most twice as large as the block size, as in all variants of AES), the probability that any $(k_1,k_2)$ makes $\operatorname{Enc}_{(k_1,k_2)}$ invertible is vanishingly small.

The title asks something significantly different:

> Is the XOR two block ciphers still a block cipher?

The difference is that we now consider two block ciphers rather than one. The answer is still *NO* in general; *NO* with "for all" $(k_1,k_2)$; and *it depends on the block ciphers but no for practical ones* with "for some".

---

The second part of the question thus is:

> If $\operatorname{Enc}_{(k_1,k_2)}$ has an inverse function, then what is $\operatorname{Dec}(k_1,k_2,c)$?

For the natural definition of $\operatorname{Dec}$, the quantity $\operatorname{Dec}(k_1,k_2,c)$ is the element $m$ of $M$ such that $E(k_1, m)\ \operatorname{XOR}\ E(k_2,m)$ equals $c$. The hypothesis "has an inverse function" makes such $m$ defined and unique.

> And how would we compute $m$ knowing $k_1$, $k_2$, and $c$?

When seeing $E$ as a black box, one way is to try all values of $m$ in $M$ (say, incrementally) until finding one that fits (which is unique under the hypothesis that $\operatorname{Enc}_{(k_1,k_2)}$ has an inverse). This search of $m$ has cost linear in $|M|$, thus is possible only for relatively small message space (e.g. a 32-bit or 48-bit block cipher). Although practical block ciphers with such small block size have been proposed (e.g. [Simon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_(cipher)), [Speck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speck_(cipher))), the *remark* above would make it a surprise that a $(k_1,k_2)$ exists making $\operatorname{Enc}_{(k_1,k_2)}$ invertible for such block ciphers, and finding one would be tantamount to a break of the block cipher.

I conjecture that it can be proven that even with black box access to both the encryption $E$ and matching decryption function $D$, there's no sub-exponential algorithm to find $m$ such that $\operatorname{Enc}_{(k_1,k_2)}=c$ when there's such $m$, which is for a sizable fraction of $c$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, you helped me a lot!